# What UIKit elements can be used to replicate the App Store/iTunes Store paged grid?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm new to Cocoa Touch, so this might be pretty easy, but I can't seem to figure out what UIKit elements were used to create a grid like this?

Is this simply a UITableView with a pagination controller? If so, how'd they style it like this?

Thanks!

PS: I'm not allowed to post images yet, i guess. hopefully the link works...

http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/8523/screenshot20100525at941.png

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `UITableView` does not have pagination. Apple uses a custom controller to produce the iPad App Store's grid layout for the featured apps.

However, you could use a third-party control, like [`AQGridView`](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView), along with `UIPageControl`.